# How to use bash commands alongside Docker restart policies?

Tags: bash, docker, ros, docker-run

In a ROS project, I have the following bash script that I use to run a docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rosnode kill some_ros_node
roslaunch supporting_ros_package launch_file.launch &

docker run -it \
    --restart=always \
    --privileged \
    --net=host \
    my_image:latest \
    /bin/bash -c\
    "
     roslaunch my_package my_launch_file.launch
    "
export containerId=$(docker ps -l -q)
```

However, what I'd like to happen is, for every time the container restarts (especially as the machine is booted up), the bash commands preceding the `docker run` command to also re-run on the host machine (not within the container).

How might I achieve this?

Comment: You'd need some kind of task manager like supervisord or a systemd unit file, on the host, that monitored the container (maybe had a non-background `docker run` as its primary command).  The Docker ecosystem largely doesn't run commands directly on the host at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways I can think of doing this:

1. Add this script to a system service. See this answer regarding adding a system service: [See this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236307)
2. Add this script into *another* container that is also set to restart always ... but mount the docker socket into this other container like this: [See this](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337/8)